# Get next to next monday in PHP

Tags: php, date

How can i get 2nd monday after the input date?
i have solution but that not feasible

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->modify('next monday');
$next_monday = $date->format('Y-m-d');
$date = new DateTime($next_monday);
$date->modify('next monday');
$next_monday = $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Please suggest me some method to do so.

Comment: see [strtotime()](http://php.net/strtotime)

Comment: what about  $date = new DateTime('next monday');
$date->modify('+7 day'); ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `DateTime` object's `modify` method takes the same type of arguments that `strtotime` does. You're already using `'next monday'`, you just need to use `'second monday'` instead.

```
$date->modify('second monday');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Also, in case you didn't know this, some of the DateTime methods can be chained:

```
echo $date->modify('second monday')->format('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with `strtotime()` but if you think it is too costly, you can use `date` and `DateInterval` as well.

```
$date = new DateTime('2017-02-15 13:03:00');
// move back to past Monday
$num = (date("w", $date->getTimestamp())) - 1;
$offset = new DateInterval("P{$num}D");
$offset->invert = 1;
// move forward two weeks
$interval = new DateInterval('P2W');
$next_second_monday = $date->add($offset)->add($interval);
```

And `$next_second_monday` will be:

```
DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2017-02-27 13:03:00.000000
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => UTC
)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is probably another way to do so but using [MomentPHP](https://github.com/fightbulc/moment.php) You could get the start of today's week, adding 1 day ( to get to monday ) and then adding two week, you would get to the second next monday.
Something like that :

```
<?php
$m = \Moment\moment();
$sunday = $m->startOf('week');
$monday = $sunday->addDays(1);
$2nextMonday = $monday->addWeeks(2);
```